# How precisely can a physiotherapist assess muscles tightness?

Tags: muscle, physiotherapy

I wonder how precisely can a physiotherapist assess muscles tightness by touching a given muscle. For example, if muscles tightness can be measured as a percentage, would a physiotherapist be able to distinguish 10% tightness from 20% tightness?

Comment: I'm a physical therapist and I check muscle tightness in comparison to the other side. So right calf against left for example. Percentage is a rather strange and IMHO not practicable approach. Also the assessment of tightness is not really helpful for my further therapy, because a tight muscle is not bad per se. Range of motion and strength are way more interesting for a physical therapist.

Answer (score 1):

As a continence and pelvic pain physiotherapist pelvic floor muscle tightness is actually an assessment of increased tone or muscle overactivity. Palpation is digital and sides are compared as are each individual muscle within the pelvic floor. Tightness/increased tone/overactivity will often manifest as trigger points or areas of pain or discomfort.
Another objective measure is by using a [perineometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perineometer) which actually gives a reading in cmH2O or mmHg and has norms to compare against.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].